# sql server ALL keyword

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Say I have the following table:

```
ID  Value
--  ----
1   1
1   1
1   0
2   1
2   1
```

let us take the ID of 1. I need to check that all of the ID's that are 1 have a value of 1.
If not, I need to return 'N/A'. In this case, since row 3 had a value of 0, I need to return 'N/A'

```
    select * from tbl1 where ID = 1 and value = 1
```

will not quite do it.

I know SQL has the ALL keyword but not sure how to use it in this case

Comment: `ALL` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: What exactly is the output that you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @id INT;
SET @id = 1;

SELECT CASE 
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tablename WHERE ID = @id AND Value <> 1) THEN 'N/A'
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tablename WHERE ID = @id) THEN 'All are equal to 1'
  ELSE 'No values present with this ID.'
END
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you also are testing if the ID = 2 then value is also = 2 and so on and so forth, that is ID = Value, if so:

```
SELECT 
      ID, 
      Value, 
      CASE WHEN ID=Value THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'N/A' END AS TheStatus 
 FROM 
      MyTable
```